# 'from A to B to C' or 'from A to B and from B to C'? How do I describe such a trend?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, expressions, syntax, phrase-choice

If I want to describe a trend, for example, a gas has a density of 1, its liquid form has a density of 2, and its solid form's density is 3, which expression will be better

> the density increases from the gas form to the liquid form to the solid form

or

> the density increases from the gas form to the liquid form and from the liquid form to the solid form

By the way, are there any better ways to describe this trend? For example, is

> the density is the lowest of the gas form and the highest of the solid form

correct?
Does it look better or worse than the two above? How do native English speakers describe such a trend?

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for gas, liquid and solid is **state**. You can eliminate a lot of the repetition in your sentences by describing what happens as the state **changes**.

> The density increases as the state changes from gas to liquid to solid.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. The 3rd one is also fine, but it doesn't show a trend.

You can also say "The density increases as the state changes from Gas to Solid" or "The density increases as the element moves from its gas state to its solid state"

You don't need to mention the liquid state as it is understood that the element changes into its liquid state before it changes into its solid state.

Hope it helps.